# how to get input from scanner to my private viarable string in another class?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

this is my first assignment, how to get input from scanner to  my private viarable string in another class?

1. Create Author class as the description mentioned below.(i already done it)
2. Create a test class called TestAuthor to test all the public methods in class Author. Below
   is the example of the output.

[the questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMt2p.png)

this is my author code

```
package assignment1;

public class Author {
    
    //attribute of the class
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private char gender;
    
    
    //constructor
    public Author(String name, String email, char gender) {
        
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    
    //methods
    public String getName() {
        
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getEmail() {
        
        return email;
    }
    
    public void setEmail(String newEmail) {
        
        this.email = newEmail;
        
    }
    
    public char getGender() {
        
        return gender;
        
    }
    //method to get data from author object 
    public String toString() {
        
        return "Author[name="+name+", email="+email+", gender="+gender+"]";
                
    }   

}
```

this is my testauthor
and i get this error
'The method getName() in the type Author is not applicable for the arguments (String)'

```
package assignment1;

import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class


public class TestAuthor {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        
        //test constructor 
        Author newAuthor = new Author();
        
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please enter name : ");
         String name = input.nextLine();
            newAuthor.getName(name);
            System.out.println("Name : "+newAuthor.getName());
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

TIA

Comment: Just remove the `name`  argument in the function call. `getName` method does not require any parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the help, i got the answer
this is my testAuthor file

```
package assignment1;

import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class


public class TestAuthor {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        //set variables()
        String name;
        String email;
        char gender;
        
        
        //Scanner input object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        //get user input
        System.out.println("Please enter Name : ");
        name= input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Please enter Email : ");
        email= input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Please enter Gender : ");
        gender= input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        
        
        //
        Author newAuthor = new Author(name,email,gender);
        name = newAuthor.getName();
        email = newAuthor.getEmail();
        gender = newAuthor.getGender();
        

        //output toString
        System.out.println(newAuthor.toString());
        
        
        //set new email
        System.out.println("Please change Email : ");
        String newEmail= input.nextLine();
        newAuthor.setEmail(newEmail);
        
        
        //output
        System.out.println("Name : "+newAuthor.getName());
        System.out.println("Email : "+newAuthor.getEmail());
        System.out.println("Gender : "+newAuthor.getGender());
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Cool, but you mention in question having trouble getting input value for private property value in a different class, anyway it works for you well.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i don't know how to say the problem, anyways thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add setter method for name property in Author class like this:

package assignment1;

public class Author {

```
//attribute of the class
private String name;
private String email;
private char gender;


//constructor
public Author(String name, String email, char gender) {
    
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.gender = gender;
}

//methods
public String getName() {
    
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
  this.name = name;
 }

public String getEmail() {
    
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String newEmail) {
    
    this.email = newEmail;
    
}

public char getGender() {
    
    return gender;
    
}
//method to get data from author object 
public String toString() {
    
    return "Author[name="+name+", email="+email+", gender="+gender+"]";
            
}
```

}

In TestAuthor class you need to call setter to set value then call like this :

package assignment1;
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class

public class TestAuthor {

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
     
    //test constructor 
    Author newAuthor = new Author();
    
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter name : ");
     String name = input.nextLine();
        newAuthor.setName(name);
        System.out.println("Name : "+newAuthor.getName());
    
}
```

}